# How to add class element to vector inside of another private class

Tags: c++, class, vector

I have made a University class that consists of vector where Degree is another class consisting of vector. All the vectors are private and I would like to use setters and getters to modify them. While testing its functionality in main() I have noticed weird behaviour:

```
University ua;
ua.setDegree(Degree("Computer Science"));
ua.getDegree(0).setStudent(Student("1101","Ria",true));
ua.getDegree(0).setStudent(Student("1102","Ava",false));
ua.setDegree(Degree("Biotechnology"));
ua.getDegree(1).setStudent(Student("1104","Vry",false));
ua.showDegrees();
```

While adding new Degrees to the ua object I can see the result while displaying them, however when I add new Student to these Degrees I don't see any change. Both Degrees remain empty. I feel like I edit their local copy and therefore I don't see the added Students. However, I don't know how could I fix it... This it the code of the setters:

```
class University {
private:
    vector<Degree> all;
    int n;
public:
    Degree getDegree(int i) {return all.at(i);}
    void setDegree(Degree degree) {all.push_back(degree); n++;}
    int getN() {return n;}
    void showDegrees() { for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {cout<<endl<<getDegree(i).getName()<<endl;} }
    University() { this->n = 0; } };

class Degree {
private:
    string name;
    vector<Student> all;
    int n;
public:
    string getName() {return name;}
    void setName(string name) {this->name = name;}
    Student getStudent(int i) {return all.at(i);}
    void setStudent(Student student) {all.push_back(student); n++;}
    vector<Student> getAll() {return all;}
    int getN() {return n;}
    Degree(string);
    Degree() {} };

Degree::Degree(string name) {
    this->name = name;
    n = 0;
}
```

Comment: "set" is not a good way to name a method which *adds* something to list. It may not seem like a big deal but it makes impossible to understand how the fist snippet works without remembering the second one.

Comment: Let me guess: you have Java background, and you are now learning C++? This is how objects work in Java, but C++ is not Java. Your getters return a complete copy of the object that's in the vector, and modifying it does absolutely nothing to the object in the vector. C++ does not work this way. Perhaps you want to return a reference instead of an object?

Comment: Like Sam has written, C++ a little different approach to passing values than your average object language. For example, you shouldn't really pass object by values in any situation when you don't have a reason to create a copy of it (which is not good for performance). Compiler should optimize such simple case as yours but keep that in mind for when your program will become bigger. Actually, if you want to really optimize it, you can look up r-value constructors and method `emplace` but that's advanced stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your getters return copies of the objects contained within your class.  If you want to be able to directly modify the class objects, you need to return by reference:

```
Degree &getDegree(int i);

Student &getStudent(int i);
```

Comment: Also, there should probably be two getters for each field. One should be `const` so it is possible to use it on a const object.